# How can I write function with this condition?

Tags: r

I need the function to return a row from the matrix, which has the least number of zeros.
For example:
the matrix

```
1:(0 0 0 2)
2:(3 0 4 3)
```

The second line has fewer zeros and we return it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rowSums` on a logical `matrix` to get the count of 0s and then wrap with `which.min` to get get the index of the least number of 0 row.

```
m1[which.min(rowSums(!m1, na.rm = TRUE)),, drop = FALSE]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    3    0    4    3
```

`drop` is added to prevent the `matrix` from coercing to a `vector` when there is only a single row/column as output from subsetting as the default option is `drop = TRUE`

#### data

```
m1 <- rbind(c(0, 0, 0, 2), c(3, 0, 4, 3))
```

Comment: How can I return this row?

Comment: And m1 is our matrix?

Comment: @МарияЗаночкина isn't that code returns the row

Comment: @МарияЗаночкина `m1` is just a placeholder for the object name. You can replace that with the correct object name.  I didn't see any reference to your object name.  So, I just called it as 'm1'

Comment: If we have random matrix how we can use it?

Comment: @МарияЗаночкина sorry, not getting your question.  It can be applied to any matrix.  If you are creating a matrix like `matrix(rnorm(5 *2), 5, 2) -> m1` (assign it to an object and do the rest as in the code

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `which.min`

```
subset(mat,seq(nrow(mat)) == which.min(rowSums(mat==0)))
```

Comment: How can I return this row ?

Comment: @МарияЗаночкина What do you mean `return this row`?

Comment: for example:mgmove <- function(mat) {
   return(sample(nrow(mat),1))
   
}

Comment: we need to do like this but with my condition

Comment: @МарияЗаночкина I think you should use `mat[sample(nrow(mat),1),,drop = FALSE]`

Comment: If we have random matrix : does subset not work?

Comment: @МарияЗаночкина `subset` only selects rows where logical conditions are met, independent with the type of matrix, e.g., random or not.

Comment: If in matrix we don't have zeros.Which row return?